# Advanced search list index out of range error

Tags: python, django, search, advanced-search

this is a code i wrote to give the result of advanced search for some subchannels that have there attributes and the values of the attributes each in a different table it gives me this error: list index out of range at line 35

```
sub_id = request.GET['sub_ch_id']
attributes = Attribute.objects.filter(subchannel_id = sub_id)
values =[]
print "attributes"
# print request
post = []
value_obj =[]
for w in attributes:
    name = w.name
    print request.GET[name]
    values.append(request.GET[name])
result_search_obj = []
flag = False
result_search = []
result = []
post = []
i = 0
f = i+1
# post_temp = ""

# print "HIIIIII", len(result_search_obj)
for j in range(0,len(attributes)):
    # print 'EREEEEEEE'
    result_search_obj+=(Value.objects.filter(attribute_id = attributes[j].id 
        , value = values[j]))
    # print '1st loop'    
for k in range(0,len(result_search_obj)):
    # print '2 loop'
    for l in range(0,len(result_search_obj)):

        result_search[k].append(result_search_obj[k].Post_id)
        # print '4 loop'
for a in range(0,len(result_search)):

    result_search.sort(len(result_search[k]))
    # print '6 loop'
for h in range(0,len(result_search)):

    post_temp = ""
    # print '3 loop'
    for g in result_search[h]:
        tmp=result_search[h]
        loc = temp[g]
        if loc == result_search[h+1][g]:
            flag = True
            post_temp = tmp[g]
            break
    post = post_temp
print post

return HttpResponse('filter_post_channel.html', {'posts' : post})
```

Comment: Is this the correct indentation for the code?

Comment: It would help if you indicated which is line 35. But here's a clue: any time you do `range(len(something))` in Python you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman - Why so?

Comment: @atomh33ls -- [because you are not Rube Goldberg](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EnSu9hHGq5o)

Comment: Because in Python you do `for item in whatever: do_something(item)`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman this is line 35 : result_search[k].append(result_search_obj[k].Post_id)                     the problem is i'm used to working with java this project had to be done with python so i'm a little bit improvising in the syntax

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're assuming that an empty list can be indexed directly to add elements at arbitrary positions. Try inserting the line...

```
result_search = [[] for o in result_search_obj]
```

...just before the line...

```
for k in range(0,len(result_search_obj)):
```

..but, as others have pointed out, you don't need to use `range(len(x))` to index multiple lists with the same index value. If you have something like...

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [4, 5, 6]
for index in range(len(list1)):
    list2[index] = list1[index]
```

...you can use...

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [4, 5, 6]
for index, value in enumerate(list1):
    list2[index] = value
```

Comment: the point is that as u see result_search_obj is a list of lists so i cannot remove the second loop because i'll be only accessing the first element of each list

Comment: Then perhaps you need to reference the `l` variable somewhere inside that loop? ;)

Comment: sorry i didn't catch that what do u mean by referencing the 1 variable inside that loop

Comment: Not `1` (one), `l` (lower-case L). If you don't reference that variable inside the loop, it seems redundant, no?

Comment: oh ok i read that wrong my bad :D anyway i did reference it by changing:                     result_search[k].append(result_search_obj[k].Post_id)                       to:                                                                               result_search[k].append(result_search_obj[k][l].Post_id)                 but it still gives the same error

Comment: intresting  the error changed from last 1 to 'Value' object does not support indexing for the same line :D

Comment: That's a different problem. Open a new question for that.